# AngularJS too much controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know it is a little bit noob question, but I just wanted to ask, that is it a good or a bad practice if I have too many controllers. Let's say I have a web app, that has around 12 views. Each view has it's own controller (and i didn't talk about the modals controllers I have too). I'm using the `ng-view` directive for "templating". I just to get some advice, that is it good or just really bad way to make it.

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
.... <!-- Styles and others -->
</head>
<body>
<div ng-view="true">

</div>
<script src="angular/angula.min.js">
<script src="app.js">
<script src="controllers/firstController.js">
<script src="controllers/secondController.js">
<script src="controllers/thirdController.js">
.
.
<script src="controllers/eleventhController.js">
<script src="factory/mainFactory.js">
</body>
</html>
```

My `app.js` has the routing functions (Routeproviders etc.).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you worry about too many controller or too many controller.js? If too many controller, I think it is not an issue because it is your design and controller objective is to serve that purpose. If too many controller.js, you might try some web build tools like grunt or gulp (create task) to compress all js. And maybe consider so lazy loading js and js dependency management like requirejs.

Comment: – hutingung I'm worrying about both of them. A couple of month ago I used yeoman fullstack generator for this. I'm just worrying about the loading time from the client side (if I'm right).

Comment: Yes. You are right to worry about that. However, you can solve it technically or managing user experience. For example, a loading screen to load the js. (browser should keep the cache). and the lazy loading might help to improve the user experience as well.

Answer (score 2):

Breaking things down in to small components is good, but you need a way of combining things for production deployment - see for example https://egghead.io/series/angular-automation-with-gulp